# Icon not displaying for internet shortcut windows 7 on desktop

Tags: c#, shortcut-file

I am creating Internet shortcut using the following code. But the icon of the shortcut which I am setting is not getting displayed in the case of desktop. But if I am manually renaming the shortcut to some other name its working fine(icon is getting loaded as shortcut image).

```
private String CreateDeskTopShortcut(String ApplicationStartupUrl, String IconFilePath)
{
    string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
    String UrlPath = deskDir + "\\" + "Test" + ".url";

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(UrlPath))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine("URL=" + ApplicationStartupUrl);
        writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + IconFilePath);
        writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
        writer.Flush();
    }

    return UrlPath;
}
```

calling the same as

```
CreateDeskTopShortcut("https://ipAddress/website/Login.aspx","E:\Setup_Local\Server.ico");
```

Comment: @BenRobinson - not true at all. I've just run his code in LINQPad and it successfully generated a shortcut.

Comment: But its servers its purpose. its working as an internet shortcut. The only problem I am facing is icon is not loading for the same. This is the accepted way for creating an internet shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Windows caches the icon path, and this persists even if you delete the file. I have no idea where this cache is stored, or if it persists beyond a reboot. My reproduction steps were as follows:

1. Call CreateDeskTopShortcut("http://www.google.co.uk", "\path\to.ico");
2. Shortcut created with expected icon.
3. Delete shortcut and call CreateDeskTopShortcut("http://www.google.co.uk", "\other-path\to.ico");
4. Shortcut created, but with icon from step 1.
5. Change shortcut name from 'Test' to 'Test2'. Repeat step 3.
6. Shortcut created, with expected icon.

So the icon used seems to be mapped to the name of the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. +1. me also came to a conclusion that there is some cache existing. Now I am creating image with a new name I am able to get an image but its of a globe image. For fixing the issue I am creating image in a temp location and then moving to desktop. After that correct image is displayed.